# PHP mailer not creating new lines

Tags: php, phpmailer, newline, mailer

No matter what i try i can't create a new line with php mailer. It sends the letter jsut fine, though no new line.

```
$msg1 = 'Prašome užpildyti šią <a href="http://192.168.0.***/bni/anketa.php?data='.$data.'&git='.$val['mailid'].'">anketą</a>.';
$msg2 = ' http://192.168.0.***/bni/anketa.php?data='.$data.'&git='.$val['mailid'];
$mail->Body= $msg1 . "\r\n" . $msg2;
$mail->send();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing html and text content-type.

Either use text only, where `\r\n` is fine, or use `<br>` which is for HTML which fits in your case (you also have `<a href..`).

```
$mail->Body= $msg1 . "<br>" . $msg2;
```

Comment: You were faster and gave more information than my answer. Deleted, and have an upvote.